# How to align a canvas and a div element side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I have a canvas and a div element which I want to split in the ratio 60% to 40%. So far any changes that I make to the display ensures that the div is displayed first and then the canvas.

And the Div element has buttons that have color changing properties for the canvas element.

```
<div id = "ModelArea1">
    <div id = "Model1">
  <canvas id ="scene1" style="width: 100%; height:100%;">
    </canvas>
    </div>
    <div id ="SelectionArea1">
        <button type ="button" class ="ButtonFormat" onclick =displayVariations()>Fabric Textures</button>
        <div class = "FabricTectureOptions" style="display:none;">  
            <div class ="Fabric1">      
            </div>
            <div class ="Fabric2">      
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type ="button" class ="ButtonFormat" onclick =displayVariations()>Leather Textures</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.Fabric1{
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/B2kPznR/Fabric-Upholstery-Moss-Plain-Weave001-AO-1-K.jpg");
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
}
.Fabric2{
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/kKZRpdm/Fabric-Upholstery-Moss-Plain-Weave001-COL-VAR3-1-K.jpg");
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
}
.ButtonFormat{
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: none outset outset none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.FabricTectureOptions{
  padding: 0 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#ModelArea1{
  width:100%;
  display:inline-flex;
}
#Model1{
  width: 60%;
}
#SelectionArea1{
  width: 40%;
}
```

What I am expecting is same height and width of the canvas and div but side by side.

```
| Canvas        |     Div  |
|               |          |
|               |          |
```

Question 1: How do I get this alignment right?

Question 2: Can this be done only by wrapping the canvas into a div? Is there an alternative?

Here is a link to the codepen:
https://codepen.io/FarhaNaseem/pen/eYgKJZW

Comment: `window.innerWidth` would set the width specifically to cover the entire area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this and it will work to an extent.

```
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth * 0.6, window.innerHeight); // Set the width of the canvas initially to 60%;
```

But then you may have to update the canvasWidth when every time the window is resized. I have also created some new container via JS and appended the child elements into it.

```
// Canvas width dynamic resize
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
   let ratio = 0.6
   let canvasWidth = window.innerWidth * ratio
   renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, window.innerHeight) // You can also manipulate this height by multiplying with the ratio
   camera.aspect = canvasWidth/ window.innerHeight
   camera.updateProjectionMatrix() // Must be called after any change of parameters.
});

// Add elements to the DOM in a wrapper container 
let ModelArea1 = document.querySelector("#ModelArea1")
let container = document.createElement("div")
container.classList.add("container")
document.body.append(container)
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement) // Append canvas to the container
container.appendChild(ModelArea1) // Append 40% area after canvas
```

This would give you a neater DOM generated:

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <canvas id="scene1" width="726" height="541">
    </canvas>

  <div id="ModelArea1">
    
    <div id="Model1">
    </div>
    
    <div id="SelectionArea1">
      <button type="button" class="ButtonFormat" onclick="displayVariations()">Fabric Textures</button>
      <div class="FabricTectureOptions" style="display:none;">
        <div class="Fabric1">
        </div>
        <div class="Fabric2">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="ButtonFormat" onclick="displayVariations()">Leather Textures</button>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Finally you can turn the container to a flexbox element using `display: flex`

**Output:**

Codepen Demo: https://codepen.io/m4n0/pen/zYNeGVz

[image]

Comment: Adding the elements onto a container works brilliantly thank you.